# Generating XML documentation for a project

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio, documentation

I am programming in VB.NET in Visual Studio and wants to generate XML documentation. I use the magical ''' comments to generate xml from my source code. When I go to the Project Properties and check the Generate XML documentation file in the Compile->General tab, each time I click it, it disappears. Do you know why ? Is there another way, for example by adding some xml into the vbproj file ?

To generate xml documentation file from my project.

Answer (score 4):

I'm seeing the same behaviour that you describe for a .NET Core app. This may be a bug in VS or just something they haven't got around to implementing properly yet. I have determined a manual workaround though.

When I first create a project, this is what I see in the properties:

[image: default XML documentation setting]

If I look at the project file, I see this:

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'" />
```

In a .NET Framework project, the equivalent box is checked by default and I see this:

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
  <DocumentationFile>WindowsApp1.xml</DocumentationFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Irrelevant lines have been removed.

If I change my .NET 6 project to this:

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
  <DocumentationFile>WinFormsApp1.xml</DocumentationFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

then the project properties changes to this:

[image: configuration-specific XML documentation setting]

You can add a separate `PropertyGroup` element for *Release* too. Alternatively, if you just add that child element to the top `PropertyGroup` that has no `Condition` attribute then it will apparently apply to all build configurations and you'll get this:

[image: coommon XML documentation setting]

It seems that that box faithfully represents a read of the project file but doesn't trigger a write properly.